# Loading Ember Data hasMany relationships using links

Tags: ember.js

I'm having some trouble getting hasMany relationships to auto load (default or async) - I'm using the "links" attribute so i can use a custom url for children, and using a custom serializer to put the links attribute in since the server doesn't provide it - is this not supported? (using ember data 1 beta 6 and ember 1.3.2)

```
App.Bag = DS.Model.extend({
    elements: DS.hasMany('element')
});
App.Element = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string')
});
App.BagSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
    extractSingle: function(store, type, payload, id, requestType) {
        payload.links = {"elements": "/bags/" + id + "/elements"};
        return this._super(store, type, payload, id, requestType);
    }
});
```

I'm able to load a Bag fine, but the elements array is never populated, I never see a call to the /bags/id/elements url. Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if this fixes your issue, but you should have inside the Element model `bag: DS.belongsTo('bag')`

Comment: I realize it's meen 2+ years, but have you figured this out? I'm struggling with a very similar situation...

Answer (score 0):

How about if you specify the `elements` relationship is `asyc`? Like this:

```
App.Bag = DS.Model.extend({
    elements: DS.hasMany('element', {async: true})
});
```